# How to integrate MWAA with Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, mwaa, elasticity

I've tried to search all over the internet a solution to integrate my environment MWAA with dynamodb. I am trying to substitute the s3 buckets to have more scale and performance on my MWAA. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more elaborate on your use case and requirements? Not aware of any native feature in MWAA service for DynamoDB. Nevertheless, you may explore the available Airflow Amazon provider library for DynamoDB and see if you can get them to fulfill your requirements.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/dynamodb/index.html

Comment: And very recently one of my peers created a new DynamoDB sensor and wrote a blog post about it.

https://medium.com/apache-airflow/amazon-dynamodb-value-sensor-for-apache-airflow-5137c23d163